# The Documents folder on WinPhone

Tags: windows-phone

In Windows Phone 8, there's a Documents folder, clearly visible via USB. Is it accessible for reading and/or writing for third party apps, please? How?

EDIT: OneDrive (formerly SkyDrive) does it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No.** The stock and system folders are not accessible through the public API, other than those that are designated through special selectors/pickers (e.g. Pictures).

This was implemented as a security feature. With that in mind, you can read contents of an SD card with a custom file/directory layout. You can find more details on the usage of these capabilities in [this MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj720573%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: SD slot is hardly commonplace on WP8. Lumias don't have it. Oh well.

Comment: Personally have a Lumia 820 that has an SD card, so there's that.

Comment: I've a 925 and it doesn't :)

Comment: But the OneDrive app writes to Documents just like that.